# Webpack Pug/HTML loaders converts capital letters to lowercase on production mode

Tags: html, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-loader, pug-loader

I am using both vue single-file components and separating of markup and logic to `.pug` and `.ts` files respectively. If you interesting why I don't unify is please see the **comments** section.

### Problem

```
import template from "@UI_Framework/Components/Controls/InputFields/InputField.vue.pug";
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

console.log(template);

@Component({
  template,
  components: {
    CompoundControlBase
  }
})
export default class InputField extends Vue {
    // ...
}
```

In development building mode exported template is correct (I beautified it for readability):

```html
<CompoundControlBase 
  :required="required" 
  :displayInputIsRequiredBadge="displayInputIsRequiredBadge"
    <TextareaAutosize 
      v-if="multiline" 
      :value="value" 
    /><TextareaAutosize>
</CompoundControlBase>
```

In production mode, my markup has been lowercased. So, the `console.log(template)` outputs:

```html
<compoundcontrolbase 
    :required=required 
    :displayinputisrequiredbadge=displayInputIsRequiredBadge 
    <textareaautosize 
        v-if=multiline 
        :value=value 
    ></textareaautosize>
</compoundcontrolbase>
```

Off course, I got broken view.

### Webpack config

```
const WebpackConfig = {

  // ...
  optimization: {
    noEmitOnErrors: !isDevelopmentBuildingMode,
    minimize: !isDevelopmentBuildingMode
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      
      {
        test: /\.vue$/u,
        loader: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/u,
        oneOf: [
          // for ".vue" files
          {
            resourceQuery: /^\?vue/u,
            use: [ "pug-plain-loader" ]
          },
          // for ".pug" files
          {
            use: [ "html-loader", "pug-html-loader" ]
          }
        ]
      },

      // ...
    ]
  }
}
```

### Comments

To be honest, I don't know why we need `?` in `resourceQuery: /^\?vue/u,` (explanations are welcome).
However, in development building mode above config works property for both `xxxx.vue` and `xxxx.vue.pug` files.

I am using below files naming convention:

- `xxx.pug`: pug file which **will not** be used as vue component template.
- `xxx.vue.pug`: pug file which will be used as vue component template.
- `xxx.vue`: single-file vue component.
- `xxx.vue.ts`: the logic of vue component. Required exported template from `xxx.vue.pug` as in `InputField` case.

Why I need `xxx.vue.ts`? Because of this:

```js
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

Neither public methods/fields nor non-default methods are visible for TypeScrpt `xxx.vue` files. For the common (non-applied) components, I can't accept it.

### Repro

[GitHub](https://github.com/TokugawaTakesi/question-webpack_production_lowercase)

#### Step 1: Install dependencies

```
npm i
```

#### Step 2: Let's check the development building first

```
npm run DevelopmentBuild
```

In line **156** of `DevelopmentBuild\EntryPoint.js`, you can check that below pug template:

```
Alpha
  Bravo OK
```

has been compiled properly:

[image]

#### Step 3: Problem on production build

```
npm run ProuductionBuild
```

You can find the lowercased tags in the column **13**:

[image]

You can also open `index.html` in your browser and check the `console.log()` output with compiled `TestComponent`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the "html-loader". It has the option `minimize` set to `true` in production mode ([html-loader/#minimize](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#minimize)).

I had a similar problem in angular and had to unset some options like (see for reference [html-minifier-terser#options-quick-reference](https://github.com/DanielRuf/html-minifier-terser#options-quick-reference)).

```js
// webpack.config.js
{
  test: /\.pug$/u,
  oneOf: [
    // for ".vue" files
    {
      resourceQuery: /^\?vue/u,
      use: [ "pug-plain-loader" ]
    },
    // for ".pug" files
    {
      use: [ "html-loader", "pug-html-loader" ]
    }
  ],
  options: {
    minimize: {                   // <----
      caseSensitive: false        // <----
    }                             // <----
  }
},
```

Comment: To everyone: looks like my editions has been rejected. Above config is invalid because `options` must be associated with certain loader. To make it work, we need `[ { loader: "html-loader", options: { minimize: { caseSensitive: true }}}, "pug-html-loader" ]` instead of   `[ "html-loader", "pug-html-loader" ]`.